# Converting C# to VB.net - Syntax Shortcuts

Tags: c#, vb.net

sorry for silly question but this is little annoying thing. In c# i could shortly Say:

```
new RolesController().SaveUserRole(Userid, cbxRoles.SelectedIndex);
```

i do not like Long Version, moreover SaveUserRole returns void :

```
RolesController rc = new RolesController()
rc.SaveUserRole(Userid, cbxRoles.SelectedIndex);
```

Question is : It is possible to do same thing - "short version" in VB ? Not below long Version...

```
Dim rc As New RolesController()
rc.SaveUserRole(Userid, cbxRoles.SelectedIndex)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the [`Call` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),  since expressions have to start with an identifier:

> You typically use the Call keyword when the called expression doesn’t start with an identifier. Use of the Call keyword for other uses isn’t recommended.

So your code should look like:

```
Call new RolesController().SaveUserRole(Userid, cbxRoles.SelectedIndex)
```

Comment: If you don't like using the 'Call' keyword you can also use: CType(New RolesController(), RolesController).SaveUserRole(Userid, cbxRoles.SelectedIndex)

Comment: @DaveDoknjas How is that better than `Call`? It's confusing at best IMHO.

Comment: @DominicKexel: I didn't say better, just another option.  Some people don't like using obscure keywords.

Answer (score -3):

Try out this web site. It will convert VB to C# or C# to VB. It works pretty good, only had 1-2 times it didn't do it right. There are some things that just can't equate 1-to-1.

[developerfusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Comment: New RolesController().SaveUserRole(Userid, cbxRoles.SelectedIndex)

Comment: No, it didn't work for you - VB doesn't allow accessing members directly on an object instantiation without the 'Call' keyword.

Comment: I see. Well as stated in my answer, it isn't 100%. But, if we look at the original question, it was not about accessing memebers on object instantiation, it was about converting C# to VB. If it was about that, then it was a poorly worded question.

Comment: BTW, I guess I can understand why someone (Tangible Software) would downvote someone that references a competing (free) product.

Comment: Nothing to do with that - I'm often impressed by the quality of some online converters, including developerfusion. It's just that if you reference a site, you really should be sure it provides an answer to the question.

Comment: @Steve - heh, i also Tried http://converter.telerik.com/ ...  I am pretty sure that everyone firtsly should use Own Brain, then Google, then stackoverflow...

Comment: I like that, should put it on a t-shirt. You never know what people tried if they dont tell you in the post.  Sometimes the info you get is so limited and there are only a couple thousand new post per second to keep up with. lol